How to communicate between Nomad jobs registered with Consul?
I have two Nomad jobs, a React frontend and a Node.js backend, both registered with Consul. How can I make requests from the frontend job to the backend job using Consul for service discovery?
for example,
1st nomad job (frontend)
2nd nomad job (backend)
both nomad jobs are registered to consul.
now how can i make request to 2nd nomad job(backend) from 1st nomad job(frontend)? ON which endpoint should i make request?
like:  BACKEND_URL=http://backend.service.consul:8080 or something?
Any examples or configuration tips would be greatly appreciated!

Hi. What do you mean by "how"? "Normally", just make a request. How would make a request without using Nomad? Do the same. What research did you do? Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77264447/is-there-a-way-2-jobs-can-communicate-on-hashicorps-nomad . Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68358370/how-can-i-connect-two-docker-containers-with-nomad  answer your question?
